# Any idea on how to recover the following latex file?

Tags: formatting

Probably something already asked somewhere else in the forum. I have a corrupted latex file which was running perfectly until yesterday.

This is the unreadable format I have now:

```
5 0 obj
<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Form/FormType 1/BBox[0 0 100 100]/Matrix[1 0 0 1 0 0]/Resources
6 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode/Length 23>>
stream

xÚS0PpW0PHWÐÎP(Î
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Many thanks

L.

Comment: This query looks like it might be related to the editing software and the operating system you use. The query's connection to TeX, LaTeX, and friends is less clear.

Comment: That's a fragment of a .pdf not a .tex file.  Have you somehow overwitten your .tex with the compiled output?  If so your best bet is to recover from backups.  If you have no backups or they're very old you *may* be able to recover *some* of the text from that file.

Comment: My USB was corrupted and windows asked me whether I wanted to fix it. After the fixing was done my .tex file become unreadable and the associated .pdf file not available for view.

Comment: Is there anywhere I could attach the .TEX file for people to have a look at?

Comment: This question doesn't seem related to TeX. Try Recuva.